# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Not able to resolve this issue

Tags: ios, uiwebview, cocoapods, wkwebview, xcode12

I am facing the above issue since a month now. I have tried all possible solutions but still in vain. Please help me to resolve this issue.

I have tried the **grep -r "UIWebView" .** command and below is the message that I am receiving now:

```
./ProjectName/Models/logs/SendEnquiry/UI/Cells/SendEnquiryDescriptionTableViewCell.swift:    //@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
Binary file ./Pods/TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework/TwitterKit matches
./Pods/TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework/Headers/TWTRTweet.h: *  Suitable for loading in a `UIWebView`, `WKWebView` or passing to Safari:
./Pods/LinkedinSwift/README.md:Linkedin Oauth Helper, depend on Linkedin Native App installed or not, using Linkdin IOS SDK or UIWebView to login
./Pods/IOSLinkedInAPIFix1/README.md:The API uses a UIWebView to authenticate against LinkedIn.
./Pods/IOSLinkedInAPIFix1/README.md:* redirectURL: has to be a http or https url (required by LinkedIn), but other than that, the endpoint doesn't have to respond anything. The library only uses the endpoint to know when to intercept calls in the UIWebView.
./Pods/IOSLinkedInAPIFix1/README.md:* presentingViewController: The view controller that the UIWebView will be modally presented from.  Passing nil assumes the root view controller.
./Pods/IOSLinkedInAPIFix1/README.md:The cancel callback is executed in case the user actively declines the authorization by pressing cancel button in the UIWebView (see illustration above).
./Pods/GoogleSignIn/CHANGELOG.md:- Supports sign-in via UIWebView rather than app switching to a browser,
Binary file ./Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn matches
Binary file ./.git/index matches
```

I have updated all related pods. Still the same issue. How to resolve this issue?

Here is the output after running **pod outdated** command:

```
The following pod updates are available:
- abseil 0.20190808 -> (unused) (latest version 1.20210324.0)
- Alamofire 4.9.1 -> 5.4.3 (latest version 5.4.3)
- BoringSSL-GRPC 0.0.3 -> 0.0.7 (latest version 0.0.19)
- BSImagePicker 2.10.3 -> 3.3.1 (latest version 3.3.1)
- CryptoSwift 0.15.0 -> (unused) (latest version 1.4.1)
- Firebase 6.16.0 -> (unused) (latest version 8.4.0)
- FirebaseAnalytics 6.2.2 -> 8.4.0 (latest version 8.4.0)
- FirebaseAuth 6.4.3 -> 8.4.0 (latest version 8.4.0)
- FirebaseCore 6.6.1 -> 8.4.0 (latest version 8.4.0)
- FirebaseCoreDiagnostics 1.2.0 -> 8.4.0 (latest version 8.4.0)
- FirebaseCrashlytics 4.0.0-beta.5 -> 8.4.0 (latest version 8.4.0)
- FirebaseFirestore 1.10.2 -> 8.4.0 (latest version 8.4.0)
- FirebaseInstallations 1.1.0 -> 8.4.0 (latest version 8.4.0)
- FirebaseInstanceID 4.3.0 -> (unused) (latest version 7.11.0)
- FirebaseMessaging 4.2.1 -> 8.4.0 (latest version 8.4.0)
- FLAnimatedImage 1.0.12 -> 1.0.16 (latest version 1.0.16)
- Floaty 4.0.1 -> 4.2.0 (latest version 4.2.0)
- GoogleAppMeasurement 6.2.2 -> 8.4.0 (latest version 8.4.0)
- GoogleDataTransport 3.3.1 -> 9.1.0 (latest version 9.1.0)
- GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport 1.3.1 -> (unused) (latest version 3.2.0)
- GoogleSignIn 4.4.0 -> 6.0.1 (latest version 6.0.1)
- GoogleUtilities 6.5.1 -> (unused) (latest version 7.5.0)
- gRPC-C++ 0.0.9 -> 1.28.2 (latest version 1.39.0-pre1)
- gRPC-Core 1.21.0 -> 1.28.2 (latest version 1.39.0-pre1)
- GTMSessionFetcher 1.3.1 -> (unused) (latest version 1.6.1)
- IQKeyboardManagerSwift 6.5.5 -> 6.5.6 (latest version 6.5.6)
- JSQSystemSoundPlayer 2.0.1 -> 2.0.1 (latest version 5.0.0)
- leveldb-library 1.22 -> 1.22.1 (latest version 1.22.1)
- libwebp 1.1.0 -> 1.2.0 (latest version 1.2.0)
- MultiSlider 1.10.6 -> 1.11.2 (latest version 1.11.2)
- nanopb 0.3.9011 -> 2.30908.0 (latest version 2.30908.0)
- PromisesObjC 1.2.8 -> 2.0.0 (latest version 2.0.0)
- Protobuf 3.11.4 -> (unused) (latest version 4.0.0-rc1)
- PusherSwift 7.2.0 -> 10.0.0 (latest version 10.0.0)
- PushNotifications 3.0.4 -> 4.0.0 (latest version 4.0.0)
- ReachabilitySwift 4.3.0 -> (unused) (latest version 5.0.0)
- SDWebImage 5.5.2 -> 5.11.1 (latest version 5.11.1)
- SDWebImageWebPCoder 0.5.0 -> 0.8.4 (latest version 0.8.4)
- Starscream 3.0.6 -> (unused) (latest version 4.0.4)
- SVPinView 1.0.7 -> 1.0.11 (latest version 1.0.11)
- SweeterSwift 1.1.2 -> 1.1.4 (latest version 1.1.4)
- SwiftLint 0.38.2 -> 0.43.1 (latest version 0.43.1)
- SwiftSoup 2.3.0 -> 2.3.2 (latest version 2.3.2)
- SwiftyGif 5.2.0 -> 5.4.0 (latest version 5.4.0)
- SwiftyJSON 5.0.0 -> 5.0.1 (latest version 5.0.1)
The following pods are deprecated:
- Crashlytics (in favor of FirebaseCrashlytics)
- Fabric (in favor of FirebaseCrashlytics)
- JSQMessagesViewController
```

Here is the Pod file content:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ProjectName' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ProjectName
  pod 'SwiftyGif'
  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'Toast-Swift'
  pod 'SharkORM'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'iOSDropDown'
  pod 'LinkedinSwift'
  pod 'BSImagePicker'
  pod 'FloatRatingView'
  pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
  pod 'SwiftSoup'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'PusherSwift'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'FLAnimatedImage'
  pod 'SVPinView'
  pod 'Floaty'
  pod 'GCCalendar'
  pod 'YYCalendar'
  pod 'TwitterKit'
  pod 'SDWebImageWebPCoder'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
   pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
   pod 'TextFieldEffects'
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
   pod 'PushNotifications'
   pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
   
#  pod "WARangeSlider"
 pod 'MultiSlider'

  target 'ProjectNameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ProjectNameUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Check `pod outdated`

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Updated the question. Please check.

Comment: You don’t say what you’ve actually tried. Have you done a `pod update` yet?

Comment: It looks like you have several very old Pods. If `pod update` doesn't update, see the resulting `Podfile.lock` to determine what is preventing the update.  Also, it may help to share the Podfile in the question.

Comment: @DavidNedrow Yes I have done it. I have got so many errors so I only updated pods which are using UIWebView.

Comment: Many of the pod recent version no longer support iOS 8, so there should be a specification like `platform :ios, '10.0'` in the Podfile

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I am unable to solve these 2 issues when I run grep -r "UIWebView" .  command.                                                                                 
Binary file ./Pods/TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework/TwitterKit matches
Binary file ./.git/index matches

Comment: My application is still getting rejected for the same UIWebview reason.